# Book identification: '90s sci-fi, "Kilimanjaro" in title

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to find a book I bought when I was younger. Here's what I can remember:

- Somewhere in 1990-1995.
- "Kilimanjaro" in the title, possibly ended in "to Kilimanjaro."
- Cover art had green on it, potentially a jungle? May have featured a character in an insect-like suit (this is very murky and could be completely incorrect).

I really don't remember much else about it, unfortunately. I think it was near-future, semi-dystopian, primarily set in Africa. I wish I could remember more, but it was lost in a move in the '90s.

Comment: Could this be [Toward Kilimanjaro](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42285)?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SciFi.SE. Can you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: [Interesting cover](http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/7/7f/IAS_1990_08_Barlowe.jpg) for "Toward Kilimanjaro". [Here](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?516991) is a green one.

Answer (score 2):

*Chaga* by Ian McDonald doesn't have “Kilimanjaro” in the title, but the “Kilimanjaro Event” is a major element of the novel, and I think everything else fits.  It was published in 1995, and was also released under the title *Evolution’s Shore*.  [Wikipedia’s extremely terse article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaga_(McDonald_novel)) summarizes its plot as:

> Told through the eyes of journalist Gaby McAslan, the novel explores the catastrophic effects of an alien flora, dubbed the "Chaga", which is brought to Kenya by a meteor in what has become known as the Kilimanjaro Event.

Goodreads has a slightly longer blurb:

> In 2003, a team of Germans hang-gliding from Mount Kilimanjaro report a large meteor strike, then manage to get one cryptic message back to their base camp—“It's growing”. When the searchers arrive, what they find will ultimately lead to the transformation of the human race by something beyond its imagination.

Here are the British and American covers:

[image: Chaga]

[image: Evolution’s Shore]

Since you mention an insect-like suit, I suspect you may have read the American edition.

There are also evidently two sequels, *Kirinya* and *Tendeléo's Story*, published in 1999 and 2000, respectively.  However, this would probably make them too late to be the book you are thinking of.  TheLethalCarrot also mentions a 1990 story by McDonald, “Toward Kilimanjaro,” which I am not familiar with, but I suspect it was a forerunner or prototype for *Chaga*.

Comment: unfortunately it's not Chaga or Towards Kilimanjaro.